# postfix smtp relay script

Tags: linux, postfix, scripting

I have a Postfix server and using it with Outlook (POP/SMTP).

I have different sender addresses for an account. 
Now I want to configure a relay for a specific sender address.
For example I have postfix for my main domain domain1.com.
Now I have a sender address that is domain2.com.

For that sender address I want that postfix to relay mail to a second SMTP server.
I think that should be possible without problems.

But the problem is that I have to create a SSH tunnel to the second server to connect to the
SMTP server.
But I cant use a persistent SSH connection so I want to know if it is possible that postfix executes some script before relaying the mail to the second SMTP server.

I already found some information for executing a script when incomming emails but I only want to establish the SSH tunnel before postfix relays the mail to the second SMTP server.

Comment: my issue resolve kindly [check answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/987962/491178)

Answer (score 2):

Exactly how you implement it is up to you, but you can create your own transport, and that transport can be a script, or daemon, etc.

If you could keep the tunnel up, it would be a breeze, you'd just set an

> domain2.com smtp:127.0.0.1:2000 (or whatever port you assigned locally)

transport up.

Answer (score 2):

Postfix doesn't support script hooking upon delivery. In order to workaround this you can setup a `crontab` to execute the a special script. This script will:

1. Setting up SSH tunnel
2. Flush queue.

First, define sender_dependent_relayhost_maps with the right-side value is your tunnel port (for example port 2525).

```
#/etc/main.cf
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sshtunnel

#/etc/postfix/sshtunnel
domain2.com smtp:[127.0.0.1]:2525
```

When the tunnel wasn't connected, postfix will *temporary* defer the email because of `Connection refused`-error. So you have no worries about losing an email.

Then setup crontab to execute above script. Here the pseudoscript to achieve those goals. Little modification from [this original script](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#dialup).

```
#!/bin/sh

#setup ssh tunnel. modify the parameter for your needs
ssh -L 2525:localhost:25 user@remote.example.com

# Start mail deliveries.
/usr/sbin/sendmail -q

# Allow deliveries to start.
sleep 10

# Loop until all messages have been tried at least once.
while mailq | grep '^[^ ]*\*' | grep domain2.com >/dev/null
do  
    sleep 10
done
```